# adding string to one ArrayList adds the string to this and to another ArrayList (Android)

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have experienced a strange issue with arrayLists. I declare and initialise two of them:

```
private ArrayList<String> arrayList1;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList2;

[..]

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
[..]
    arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and when I add a string to one of them, it adds automatically to the other:

```
arrayList1.add(new String("string1"));
```

Both add happen in this line, I have checked it a lot of times using breakpoints. At first I thought that it had to be something related with passing the reference instead of the value and I changed .add("string1") to .add(new String("String1")) but it didn´t work.

After a while I noticed that the two arrays had this Id that shows the Logcat the same:

```
arrayList1 = {java.util.ArrayList@830033171248} size = 1
arrayList2 = {java.util.ArrayList@830033171248} size = 1
```

Maybe this is creating the problem, but I can´t imagine why this happens and how to solve it. I am beginning with android development, so maybe this is a stupid question ,but I have tried to find the explanation for a long time without success. 
Thank you very much!
Regards!

**EDIT:**

- I have changed the name and the place in the code of the two arrayList and the problem seems to have disappeared. I am trying to reproduce the issue again.
- There is nothing similar to arrayList1 = arrayList2 in the code.
- When the arrayLists were initialised at onCreate method, the numbers after ArrayList@ were different, but I don't know why nor where it unexpectedly changed at somewhere unknown. I had breakpoints at every method and the addresses of the arrays didn´t change in any of them. I have several checkbox in the UI, and when I checked one of them, in the listener of the checkbox I could see that the address of the arrayLists (numbers after ArrayList@) had changed and had became the same. Very annoying and strange.

Comment: Are you sure that somewhere this doesn't happen: `arrayList2 = arrayList1;`?

Comment: @AlbertoC: Well that certainly *is* happening somwehere. It's not in the code you've shown us, so you need to find out where it actually is happening. Something, somewhere is giving those two variables the same value.

Comment: Pay attention to your log, after `ArrayList@` numbers that indicate the address in the memory, and as you can see they are the same

Comment: It's not the memory address. It is the hash code.

Answer (score 3):

It's clear that both of your variables point to the same instance of ArrayList, and we know that Java definitely handles references just fine, so we have to assume that there's an issue with some code that you haven't included where you are doing something like `arrayList1 = arrayList2`

If you post a stripped-down code sample that reproduces the problem, then we can provide more help.

Answer (score 0):

declare **private ArrayList arrayList1=new ArrayList();** above oncreate(), make sure you are not using **array1=array2** , **array1.addAll(array2)** etc....

Answer (score 0):

May seem foolish, but have you tried doing:

```
arrayList1.add("string1");
arrayList2.add("string2");
```

If not the case, seems something wrong with pointers, Java and your PC setup with it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create the objects with their declarations

```
private ArrayList<String> arrayList1=new ArrayList<String>(); 
private ArrayList<String> arrayList2=new ArrayList<String>();
```

It's also better to specifiy `String`, the type of items in the array

Comment: no it is not. The second <String> is redundant and was replaced by the diamond notation in java 7